# How to Save GridView Data's to Access Database in Winforms DevExpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I Have GridView in the Form and Attached DataSource to it. 1st Column having Repository_Grid_Lookup_Edit and Attached DataSource to it. I perform Some Calculation and Obtain some results. So now Totally 5 Rows and 6 Columns in the gridView. I have Save Button in the same Form, If i click Save Button I want to Store All this Data's to New Table in the GridView ?? How to Complete my Task.

Thanks in Advance.
Sri

Comment: What you tried till now?

Comment: Are you using a datatable as datasource?

Comment: Hi Kalyan,       I tried this code but error                                ColumnView View = (ColumnView)grid.FocusedView;
    if (!(View.PostEditor() && View.UpdateCurrentRow())) return;
    
    //Update the database's Suppliers table to which oleDBDataAdapter1 is connected 
    DoUpdate(oleDbDataAdapter1, dataSet11.Tables["Suppliers"]);

Comment: Hi Tarik, Am new to DevExpress I used DataSource to Bind Data. But dono exactly how to save data to Data Source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView is just a View on the datas which you DataSource holds. So if you change some value in the GridView the underlying DataSource automaticly changes the value. I recommend you to build a class which represents one data set. Then you create a `List<MyClass>` and use this as DataSource. So your BusinessObjects change automaticly if someone edit a value in the Grid.

To your question:
If you want to show the data in a new Table just create a new Grid and populate the `List<MyClass>` again. If you want to show the saved data only clone you `List<MyClass>` on SaveButton Click and populate it.

I hope i understand you. If you need further help i post an short example.

regards

Comment: Hi Sebi, thanks for answering I get an Idea now. I will contact if any doubts.